# Beamer ToC: display all sections and subsections at first, then subsequent current section, subsections/subsubsetions

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning

My current slides are designed to display the current section and subsections/subsubsections at the beginning of every section.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{default} 

\title[MyUNI] 
{The Paper Title ...}
\author[F.~Author, S.~Author \& L.~Author] 
{F.~Author\inst{1} S.~Author\inst{1,}\inst{2} \and L.~ Author\inst{1,}\inst{3}}

\institute[UNI] 
{
  \inst{1}%
  The University 
  \and
  \inst{2}%
    Institute ABC
  \and
  \inst{3}%
  Lab XYZ
}

\date[VLC2021] 
{The Conference 2021  \\October 15-19, 2021}

\AtBeginSection[]
{\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{ToC}  
 \tableofcontents[currentsection,
                  hideothersubsections,
                  subsubsectionstyle=show/show/show/hide
                   ]
 \end{frame} 
 }
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\section{Introduction}
    \subsection{Conceptual Framework}
    \begin{frame}{Conceptual Framework}
        \begin{figure}
           \centering
          \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-c}
          \caption{Conceptual framework.}
         \end{figure}
    \end{frame}

\section{Data Anlysis}
    \subsection{Method 1}
    \subsection{Method 2}

\section{Proposed Algorithm}
    \subsection{Algo\_blah}
    \subsubsection{hypothesis test 1}
    \subsubsection{hypothesis test 2}
    \subsubsection{hypothesis test 3}

\begin{frame}{Review}
    Some text here.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I want to display all of the sections and subsections on the first entry (i.e. just after the title slide), so I can talk about the structure of my presantation give people over the figure of my talk right before I start.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a switch to decide whether this is the first ToC or not. If it's the first displayed ToC show everything, else show only the current section. The following does that by introducing `\iffirsttoc`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{default} 

\title[MyUNI] 
{The Paper Title ...}
\author[F.~Author, S.~Author \& L.~Author] 
{F.~Author\inst{1} S.~Author\inst{1,}\inst{2} \and L.~ Author\inst{1,}\inst{3}}

\institute[UNI] 
{
  \inst{1}%
  The University 
  \and
  \inst{2}%
    Institute ABC
  \and
  \inst{3}%
  Lab XYZ
}

\date[VLC2021] 
{The Conference 2021  \\October 15-19, 2021}

\newif\iffirsttoc
\firsttoctrue

\AtBeginSection[]
{\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{ToC}  
 \iffirsttoc
   \tableofcontents
   \global\firsttocfalse
 \else
   \tableofcontents[currentsection,
                    hideothersubsections,
                    subsubsectionstyle=show/show/show/hide
                     ]
 \fi
 \end{frame} 
 }
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\section{Introduction}
    \subsection{Conceptual Framework}
    \begin{frame}{Conceptual Framework}
        \begin{figure}
           \centering
          \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-c}
          \caption{Conceptual framework.}
         \end{figure}
    \end{frame}

\section{Data Anlysis}
    \subsection{Method 1}
    \subsection{Method 2}

\section{Proposed Algorithm}
    \subsection{Algo\_blah}
    \subsubsection{hypothesis test 1}
    \subsubsection{hypothesis test 2}
    \subsubsection{hypothesis test 3}

\begin{frame}{Review}
    Some text here.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me

Comment: @mina you could ask a follow up question showing your MWE that doesn't work for you (maybe with a link to this answer). I can only guarantee that the code above worked in 2021.